# How to pull variables out of a string

Tags: java, variables, configuration, properties

I'm looking for a Java class that for a given string "the ${animal} jumped over the ${target}." is able to pull out the variable names, ie 'animal' and 'target'.

I had hoped [StrSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) in Commons Lang had a method
`getVariables(String str) : List<String>`
... but no such luck.

Yes I could write this myself, but I'm certain there must be a 3rd party library that exists out there that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a simple regex match if you really just want to pull out those values and avoid the dependency of an entire library:

```
public List<String> getVariableNames(String source) {
  List<String> vs = new ArrayList<String>();
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
  while (m.find()) {
    vs.add(m.group(1));
  }
  return vs;
}
```

Storing the pattern as a member variable will improve performance.

Comment: Nice solution. I used this in the end for a couple reasons;
* I control the strings, so no chance of nested elements or any other wackyness breaking the regex.
* Basic, way less pitfalls than a more complex solution.
Thanks again. PS Would still love to see this in Commons though, ha!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was also looking for a similar library while developing [DSL Adapter](http://anubhava.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/introducing-dsl-adapter-for-generic-fixture/) for my [GenericFixture](http://anubhava.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/introducing-generic-fixture-for-fitnesse/).

After looking at some libraries and template based framework I eventually decided to write code by myself. Feel free to check the code I used for this purpose in `DSLAdapter class` from [GenericFixture available on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/genericfixture/files/).